# Пропадает после подключения скрипта иконка корзины

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Скачал отсюда корзину интернет магазина потому что сам ещё написать не могу. после подключения скрипта она пропадает
вот корзина которую скачал

```js
/***************************************
 * JQuery based script     
 * Basket on client side     
 * Created WebInside WebStudio (c) 2014 
 * Use only for linked www.webinside.ru 
 **************************************/

var local = {
  "basket_is_empty": "Корзина пуста",
  "name": "Название",
  "price": "Цена",
  "all": "Всего",
  "order": "Оформить заказ",
  "basket": "корзина",
  "num": "кол-во",
  "send": "Спасибо за покупку!\nМы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время",
  "goods": "Товаров",
  "amount": "на сумму"
};

function WICard(obj, plugins) {
  this.widjetX = 0;
  this.widjetY = 0;
  this.widjetObj;
  this.widjetPos;
  this.cardID = "";
  this.DATA = {};
  this.IDS = [];
  this.objNAME = obj;
  this.CONFIG = {};
  this.IMG = "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";


  this.init = function(widjetID, config) {
    this.CONFIG = config || {};
    try {
      this.DATA = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(widjetID));
      if ($.isEmptyObject(this.DATA)) {
        this.DATA = {};
      }
    } catch (e) {
      this.DATA = {};
    }
    try {
      this.IDS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(widjetID + "_ids"));
      if ($.isEmptyObject(this.IDS)) {
        this.IDS = [];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      this.IDS = [];
    }

    this.cardID = widjetID;

    this.widjetObj = $("#" + widjetID);


    if ($.isEmptyObject(this.DATA)) {
      this.widjetObj.html(local.basket_is_empty);
    } else {
      this.reCalc();
      this.renderBasketTable();
    }

  }

  /***********************************************************************************************
   * example: onclick="cart.addToCart(this, '2', 'Name of comic 2', '25500')      
   **********************************************************************************************/
  this.addToCart = function(curObj, id, params) {
    var kol = 1;

    if ($("input").is("#" + wiNumInputPrefID + id)) {
      kol = parseInt($("#" + wiNumInputPrefID + id).val());
    }

    id = ($.isNumeric(id)) ? "ID" + id.toString() : id;

    var id_ = ($.isEmptyObject(params.subid)) ? id : id + "_" + params.subid;


    var goodieLine = {
      "id": id_,
      "name": params.name,
      "price": params.price,
      "num": kol,
      "url": document.location.href,
      "photo": ""
    };

    if ($.isEmptyObject(this.DATA)) {
      this.DATA[id_] = goodieLine;
      this.IDS.push(id_);
    } else
      for (var idkey in this.DATA) {


        if ($.inArray(id_, this.IDS) === -1) {
          this.DATA[id_] = goodieLine;
          this.IDS.push(id_)

        } else
        if (idkey == id_) {

          this.DATA[idkey].num += kol;

        }
      }

    localStorage.setItem(this.cardID, JSON.stringify(this.DATA));
    localStorage.setItem(this.cardID + "_ids", JSON.stringify(this.IDS));
    this.reCalc();

    this.renderBasketTable();

    if (this.CONFIG.showAfterAdd) {
      cart.showWinow('bcontainer', 1);
    }
  }
  this.reCalc = function() {
    var num = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    for (var idkey in this.DATA) {
      num += parseInt(this.DATA[idkey].num);
      sum += parseFloat(parseInt(this.DATA[idkey].num) * parseFloat(this.DATA[idkey].price));
    }

    // *** currency plugin *** //

    if (typeof WICartConvert == 'function') {
      sum = WICartConvert(sum);
    }

    // *** //     
    this.widjetObj.html(local.goods + " " + num + " " + local.amount + " " + sum + " Руб.");
    localStorage.setItem(this.cardID, JSON.stringify(this.DATA));
  }
  this.clearBasket = function() {
    this.DATA = {};
    this.IDS = [];
    this.widjetObj.html(local.basket_is_empty);
    localStorage.setItem(this.cardID, "{}");
    localStorage.setItem(this.cardID + "_ids", "[]");
    $("#btable").html('');
    $("#bcontainer").remove();
    $("#blindLayer").remove();
  }
  this.renderBasketTable = function() {

    if ($('#bcontainer').length == 0) {
      $("body").append(" \
    <div id='blindLayer' class='blindLayer'></div> \
    <div id='bcontainer' class='bcontainer'> \
    <div id='bsubject'>" + local.basket + "<a id='bclose' href='#' onclick='" + this.objNAME + ".closeWindow(\"bcontainer\", 1);'><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," + this.IMG + "' /></a></div> \
    <table id='bcaption'><tr><td>ID</td><td>" + local.name + "</td><td>" + local.price + "</td><td>" + local.num + "</td><td>" + local.all + "</td><td></td></tr></table> \
    <div id='overflw'><table class='btable' id='btable'></table></div> \
    <div id='bfooter'> <button class='bbutton' onclick=\"cart.showWinow('order', 1)\">" + local.order + "</button><span id='bsum'>...</span></div> \
    </div> \
   ");

    } else {
      $("#btable").html("");
    }
    this.center($("#bcontainer"))

    for (var idkey in this.DATA) {

      with(this.DATA[idkey]) {
        var productLine = '<tr class="bitem" id="wigoodline-' + id + '"> \
             <td>' + id + '</td> \
             <td><a href="' + url + '">' + photo + name + '</a></td> \
             <td id="lineprice_' + id + '"class="wigoodprice">' + price + ' руб.</td> \
             <td> \
             <div class="basket_num_buttons" id="minus_' + id + '">-</div> \
             <span class="basket_num" id="basket_num_' + id + '">' + num + '</span> \
             <div class="basket_num_buttons" id="plus_' + id + '">+</div></td> \
             <td id="linesum_' + id + '">' + parseFloat(price * num) + ' руб.</td> \
             <td><a href="#" onclick="' + this.objNAME + '.delItem(\'' + id + '\')"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.IMG + '" /></a></td> \
             </tr>';
      }
      $("#btable").append(productLine);

      $(".basket_num_buttons").data("min-value");
    }
    //* кнопки +/-
    var self = this;
    for (var ids in this.IDS) {
      $('#minus_' + this.IDS[ids]).bind("click", function() {
        var cartItemID = $(this).attr("id").substr(6);
        var cartNum = parseInt($("#basket_num_" + cartItemID).text());
        var cartNum = (cartNum > 1) ? cartNum - 1 : 1;
        self.DATA[cartItemID].num = cartNum;

        $("#basket_num_" + cartItemID).html(cartNum);
        var price = parseFloat($("#lineprice_" + cartItemID).html());
        $("#linesum_" + cartItemID).html(parseFloat(price * cartNum) + ' руб.');

        self.sumAll();

        self.reCalc();

      });

      $('#plus_' + this.IDS[ids]).bind("click", function() {
        var cartItemID = $(this).attr("id").substr(5);
        var cartNum = parseInt($("#basket_num_" + cartItemID).text());
        var cartNum = (cartNum < 1000000) ? cartNum + 1 : 1000000;
        self.DATA[cartItemID].num = cartNum;
        $("#basket_num_" + cartItemID).html(cartNum);
        var price = parseFloat($("#lineprice_" + cartItemID).html());
        $("#linesum_" + cartItemID).html(parseFloat(price * cartNum) + ' руб.');

        self.sumAll();
        self.reCalc();

      });

    }
    this.sumAll();

  }
  this.sumAll = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var idkey in this.DATA) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.DATA[idkey].price * this.DATA[idkey].num);
    }
    $("#bsum").html(sum + " руб.");
  }
  this.center = function(obj) {

    obj.css({
      "top": "200px"
    });
    obj.css({
      "left": Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(obj).outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"
    });
    return obj;
  }
  this.showWinow = function(win, blind) {
    $("#" + win).show();
    if (blind)
      $("#blindLayer").show();
  }
  this.closeWindow = function(win, blind) {
    $("#" + win).hide();
    if (blind)
      $("#blindLayer").hide();
  }
  this.delItem = function(id) {
    if (confirm("Удалить #" + id + "?")) {
      $("#btable").html("");
      delete this.DATA[id];
      this.IDS.splice($.inArray(id, this.IDS), 1);
      this.reCalc();
      this.renderBasketTable();
      localStorage.setItem(this.cardID, JSON.stringify(this.DATA));
      localStorage.setItem(this.cardID + "_ids", JSON.stringify(this.IDS));
      if (this.IDS.length == 0)
        this.widjetObj.html(local.basket_is_empty);
    }
  }
  this.sendOrder = function(domElm) {
    var bodyHTML = "";
    var arr = domElm.split(",");

    for (var f = 0; f < arr.length; f++) {

      bodyHTML += this.getForm(arr[f]) + "<br><br>";

    };
    $('.basket_num_buttons').remove();
    $.post("sendmail.php?subj=Order WICart", {
      "order": bodyHTML
    }).done(function(data) {
      cart.closeWindow("bcontainer", 1)
      cart.closeWindow("order", 0);
      if (cart.CONFIG.clearAfterSend) {
        cart.clearBasket();
      }
      alert(local.send);
    });

  }
  this.getForm = function(formId) {
    var formObj = document.getElementById(formId);
    var copyForm = formObj.cloneNode(true);

    INPUTS = [].slice.call(copyForm.querySelectorAll("input,textarea"));

    INPUTS.forEach(function(elm) {
      if ((elm.tagName == 'INPUT') && ((elm.type == 'text') || (elm.type == 'hidden'))) {
        var subjP = document.createElement('b');
        subjP.innerHTML = elm.placeholder;
        elm.parentNode.insertBefore(subjP, elm);
        var spanReplace = document.createElement("div");
        spanReplace.innerHTML = elm.value;
        elm.parentNode.replaceChild(spanReplace, elm);
      } else
      if (elm.tagName == 'TEXTAREA') {
        var subjP = document.createElement('b');
        subjP.innerHTML = elm.placeholder;
        elm.parentNode.insertBefore(subjP, elm);
        var spanReplace = document.createElement("div");
        spanReplace.innerHTML = $("#" + elm.id).val();
        elm.parentNode.replaceChild(spanReplace, elm);
      }
    });


    return copyForm.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

```css
/*******************************
 *
 *******************************/

.bird {
  /*border: 4px solid #999;*/
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
  /*background: #F0F0F0;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.blindLayer {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1001;
  display: none;
}

.bcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 8px solid #999;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1002;
}

#overflw {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}

#bcaption {
  background: #C0C0C0;
}

#bcaption td {
  border-right: 2px solid #999;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#bcaption td {
  padding: 5px;
}

#bcaption td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 50px;
}


/*ID*/

#bcaption td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 300px;
}


/*NAME*/

#bcaption td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 100px;
}


/*PRICE*/

#bcaption td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 150px;
}


/*NUM*/

#bcaption td:nth-child(5) {
  width: 70px;
}


/*SUM*/

.bitem td {
  font: normal 18px Arial;
  color: #999;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  border-right: 2px solid #FFF;
}

.bitem td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 50px;
}

.bitem td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 300px;
}

.bitem td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bitem td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bitem td:nth-child(5) {
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

#bclose {
  float: right;
}

.bcontainer table {
  width: 100%;
}

.bbutton {
  color: #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  padding: 5px;
  font: bold 16px Arial;
  float: right;
}

#bsum {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 20px;
  font: normal 18px Arial;
}

.popup {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F2F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #808040;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -265px;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  width: 550px;
  z-index: 2002;
  display: none;
}

.popup h4 {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.popup form {
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.popup input[type="text"] {
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.popup .alignCenter {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.popup textarea {
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}

.basket_num {
  padding: 4px;
  background: #F0F0F0;
}

.basket_num_buttons {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h1 {
  color: #004080;
  font: bold 20px Arial;
}

.cart {
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #004080;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font: normal 11px Arial;
}

.price {
  margin: 10px;
  font: normal 16px Arial;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <title>Wicart ver2.0</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/theme1.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wicart.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- WI-JQ-HEADER -->
  <script src="wicart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- WI-HEADER -->
  <style>
    .v {
      border: 1px solid #999;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      width: 340px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var priceList = {
      "001": {
        "id": "001",
        "subid": {},
        "name": "IPhone 5",
        "price": "20500"
      },
      "002": {
        "id": "002",
        "subid": {},
        "name": "IPad MINI",
        "price": "10500"
      }
    };
  </script>
  <h1>Пример JQuery корины для сайта</h1>

  <div class="cart">
    <div class="price">
      <a href="#" id="basketwidjet" onclick="cart.showWinow('bcontainer', 1)"><img src="cart.png"></a>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center"><a href="#!" onclick="cart.clearBasket()">Очистить корзину</a></div>
  </div>
  <!-- WI-BASKET -->


  <div class="v">
    <div><img class="im" src="img/iphone5.png" /></div>
    Цена: <span class="wicartprice" id="wicartprice_001">20500</span> Руб.</p>
    <button id="wicartbutton_001" onclick="cart.addToCart(this, '001', priceList['001'])">Купить</button>
  </div>

  <div class="v">
    <div><img class="im" src="img/ipad.png" /></div>
    Цена: <span class="wicartprice" id="wicartprice_002">10500</span> Руб.</p>
    <!-- WI-VETRINE[002] -->
    <button id="wicartbutton_002" onclick="cart.addToCart(this, '002', priceList['002'])">Купить</button>
  </div>

  <!---Форма для магазина-------------------------------->
  <div id="order" class="popup">
    <a href="#" onclick="cart.closeWindow('order', 0)" style="float:right">[закрыть]</a>
    <h4>Введите ваши контактные данные</h4>

    <form id="formToSend">
      <input id="fio" type="text" placeholder="Ваши фамилия и имя" class="" />
      <input id="city" type="text" placeholder="Город" class="text-input" />
      <input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Контактный телефон" class="text-input" />
      <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Электронная почта" class="" />
      <br>
      <textarea id="question" placeholder="Адрес"></textarea>
    </form>
    <button onclick="cart.sendOrder('formToSend,overflw,bsum');" href="#">Отправить заказ</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var cart;
    var config;
    var wiNumInputPrefID;
    /* WI-GLOBAL-VARS */
    $(document).ready(function() {
      cart = new WICard("cart");
      config = {
        'clearAfterSend': true,
        'showAfterAdd': false
      };

      cart.init("basketwidjet", config);
      /* WI-MODULES */


    });
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(e) {
      cart.init("basketwidjet", config);
    }, false);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Возможно вы забыли расположить картинки в правильном каталоге, или прописать верные пути?